# Keyboard Shortcut for a Specific Emoji in Yosemite 

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite

I just got a new [KBC Poker II](http://deskthority.net/wiki/KBC_Poker_II) and am playing around with the programmable key mapping. I'd like to bind one of my keyboard keys to the poop emoji () for maximum speed. Is there a quick keyboard shortcut I can use to input a *specific* emoji character like the pile of poo?

I know that you can bring up an emoji input panel in Yosemite with the keyboard shortcut Shift + Apple + Space, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want the pile of poo to squeeze directly out of my keyboard and onto the screen without having to go through the emoji panel.

Comment: "pile of poo to squeeze directly out of my keyboard". What a wonderful visual :)

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS you can use the keyboard shortcut cmd+ctrl+space to bring up the emoji pallet and then just start typing the name of an emoji character:

[image]